# How to find a control and change it to checked/unchecked from Code-Behind (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, nullreferenceexception, code-behind

I have these radio buttons:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(5);" id="star10" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Excelsior! - 5 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(4.5);" id="star9" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Almost Perfect - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(4);" id="star8" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(3.5);" id="star7" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Above Average - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(3);" id="star6" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Average - 3 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(2.5);" id="star5" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Adequate - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(2);" id="star4" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Underwhelming - 2 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(1.5);" id="star3" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Weak - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(1);" id="star2" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Bad - 1 star"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" onclick="setRating(0.5);" id="star1" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" title="Atrocious - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

I want to loop through them all to set their state without having to do something like a `switch statement` so I tried the below:

```
for (double i = 0; i < 5; i+=0.5)
{
    if(pOld.OverallRating == i)
    {
        //Stars are 1-10 but display as x/5 (where 5 is star10, 4.5/5 is star9 etc)
        Control con = FindControl("star"+i);
        ((RadioButton)con).Checked = true;
    }
}
```

There seems to be an issue with how I'm using `FindControl` but I can't see why - I'm getting a null reference exception.

EDIT1:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton'.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs are named `star1, star2... star10`, but your loop sets `i` to 0, 0.5, 1... 5, so you'll be looking for control with id `star0`, `star0.5` etc. which don't exist

Assuming you don't want to have a checkbox representing 0 stars you'll want to do something like this:

```
for (double i = 0.5; i <= 5; i+=0.5)
{
    if(pOld.OverallRating == i)
    {
        //Stars are 1-10 but display as x/5 (where 5 is star10, 4.5/5 is star9 etc)
        var id = i * 2;
        Control con = FindControl("star"+id);
        ((HtmlInputRadioButton)con).Checked = true;
    }
}
```

which will look for inputs with id `star1, star2... star10`

EDIT:
To answer the updated question - you're trying to cast a control of type `HtmlInputRadioButton` to a `RadioButton` - instead cast to `HtmlInputRadioButton`

Comment: Ah you are right yes, the exception I'm getting now however is (See #EDIT1)

Comment: @Sanguine you're casting your controls to the wrong type - swap `(RadioButton)` for `(HtmlRadioButton)`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. `The type or namespace name 'HtmlRadioButton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Sanguine you need to add a using statement to the top of your class definition - It will be something like `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`

Comment: @Sanguine the error message says it's of type `HtmlInputRadioButton`

Comment: @Sanguine We all have those days :)